# Navigation Controller not working after adding Tabbar controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have downloaded a project code from github. Now when i am adding tabbar controller in the project programmatically and setting the tabbar controller as root view controller, navigation controller is not working. Can anyone please help here.

Below is the link to access the project.

https://github.com/BytePixelMelody/FashionStoreApp

Quick help will be highly appreciated.